# Giteye: unable to locate library files

Tags: git, github, version-control, giteye

I downloaded Giteye for Windows 10 and it had `.zip` file. I extracted it and ran `giteye.exe` file, I got an error popup message saying:

> GitEye Executable unable to locate its companion shared library.

Any light on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I extracted the contents of the downloaded .zip folder using 7-zip and ran eclipsec.exe which ran GitEye.

Comment: You can mark your answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer.